# Map Kotlin data objects to data objects with enum attributes

Tags: kotlin

I have the following function that should map from one data class to another but it is not working:

```
private fun ClassA.toClassB() = ClassB(

  text = text,
  meta = meta,
  message = message)
```

ClassB is underlined in red with the error `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied`.

However, just mapping the attribute `text` works fine:

```
private fun ClassA.toClassB() = ClassB(

  text = text)
```

So I guess the upper code doesn't work because of the enum attributes.

ClassA and ClassB look exactly the same, like this:

```
data class ClassB(
  @JsonProperty("text")
  val text: String,
  @JsonProperty("meta")
  val meta: Meta?,
  @JsonProperty("message")
  val message: Message?,
) {

  constructor(text: String) : this(
    text = text,
    meta = null,
    message = null,
  )


  enum class Meta {
    ONE, TWO, THREE
  }

  enum class Message {
    ONE, TWO
  }}
```

So how can I map data classes that use enum attributes?

Comment: Try removing data keyword

Comment: @DeePanShu I did and it's still throwing that error.

Comment: check if there is a class name same as ClassB in your whole project

Comment: @DeePanShu Yes, it's java class however (ClassB.java)

Comment: Please, try to change the name or exclude java class or include your class package

Comment: @DeePanShu I don't think it's conflicting because writing this is working: private fun `ClassA.toClassB() = ClassB(text = text)`

Comment: Then were are you stuck now

Comment: In your code snippet, it seems like you define the enum classes `Meta` and `Message` within the scope of `ClassB`. A typo or on purpose?

Comment: @ogjtech That's on purpose.

Comment: @DeePanShu I specified the question now.

Comment: I think that's your problem then, will post an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your Error

"ClassA and ClassB look exactly the same" -> This results in "duplicate" enums:

`Meta` & `Message` exist both in `ClassA` *and in* `ClassB`

This leads to the following error:

```
private fun ClassA.toClassB() = ClassB(
  text = text, // ok
  meta = meta, // expected: ClassB.Meta, provided: ClassA.Meta
  message = message // expected: ClassB.Message, provided: ClassA.Message
)
```

You now have two options:

---

### You only really need one enum

- move one somewhere toplevel
- remove the other one
- make sure you fix your imports

---

### You actually need two different enums

e.g.

```
// ClassA
enum class Meta {
    ONE, TWO, THREE
  }

// ClassB
enum class Meta {
    UNO, DOS, TRES
  }
```

Then i suggest you create a function like:

```
private fun ClassA.Meta.toClassBMeta() =
    when(this){
        ClassA.Meta.ONE -> ClassB.Meta.UNO,
        ClassA.Meta.TWO -> ClassB.Meta.DOS,
        ClassA.Meta.THREE -> ClassB.Meta.TRES,
    }
```

Use it in your mapper:

```
private fun ClassA.toClassB() = ClassB(
  text = text,
  meta = meta.toClassBMeta(),
  message = message.toClassBMessage())
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Can you help me with how to write the function `private fun ClassA.Meta.toClassBMeta(): ClassB.Meta` to map the enums? I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it very much and learned cool new syntax there :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in the way you have defined your enums. It seems in your code snippet that you defined them within the scope of ClassB. You stated the contents of both ClassA and ClassB are identical, so I'm assuming you defined the enums in both. This is where your problem lies.

When compiling, every object creates a sort of "signature" as a unique identifier, so that the compiler knows ClassA from ClassB. Since you define the enums in both classes, they too get unique signatures.

So, instead of having 2 signatures for the enums, you have 4. The compiler tries cloning it (which is essentially what you're doing), but fails because it tries to directly map to an enum with a different signature.

Quite literally "same same, but different, but still same".

What you should try to do is define the enums outside of the classes.

```kotlin
namespace com.path1
{
  enum class Meta {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
  }

  enum class Message {
    ONE,
    TWO
  }

  data class ClassA(
    @JsonProperty("text")
      val text: String,
    @JsonProperty("meta")
      val meta: Meta? = null,
    @JsonProperty("message")
      val message: Message? = null
  ) {}
}

namespace com.path2 {
  import com.path1.Meta
  import com.path2.Message

  data class ClassB(
    @JsonProperty("text")
      val text: String,
    @JsonProperty("meta")
      val meta: Meta? = null,
    @JsonProperty("message")
      val message: Message? = null
  ) {}
}
```

Above code will compile only 2 signatures for the enums. Assuming the contents of your classes remain identical, they will now both use the same signature for the enum classes.

Also notice how I deleted your constructor. If you want every parameter to be instantiable by default, omit defining a constructor completely, as the way you defined the properties in the class form a constructor already.

Comment: The secondary constructor defined like this most likely won't compile because of signature conflict with the primary one. Why declare it at all? Also `toClassB()` is user-defined, it's in the question.

Comment: @Joffrey Good point, will update my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer. I need the `constructor(text: String) `somewhere else in my code though. Is there a way for it to work while still retaining the constructor?

Comment: You can do that, both enum properties are nullable, so just default them to `null` in the property declaration. Like so: `val meta: Meta? = null, val message: Message? = null`. That way, when instantiating in code like `val classB = ClassB(text = "test")`, all other properties will default to null. See edited answer

Comment: @ogjtech Okay I see, that's very cool. I forgot to mention that ClassA and ClassB are in different folders. I get a new error now saying `Type mismatch. Required: com.path1.Meta Found: com.path2.Meta`

Comment: You need to ensure both classes use the same type from the same namespace. So make sure both classes use either `com.path1.Meta` or `com.path2.Meta`, depending on which is best. I have edited my question to explain what I mean.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you @ogjtech I learned a bunch. Is there also a way to map the enums with them staying in their respective classes and files? E.g. using toString() to compare the String representations of them and then mapping them or something like that?

Comment: I'm not very well-versed in Kotlin enums yet, but a quick search came up with this result: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enum-classes-in-kotlin/, perhaps that might help?

Comment: Also, here is Kotlin's own specification on enums: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-enum/